# Representing a stack using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

I can't seem to understand pointers in C++, I hope my example could help you guide me
I have the following code:

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;
```

first class:

```
    class Node
    {
    private:
        int value;
        Node *next;
    public:
        Node()
       {
            value = 0;
       }
       ~Node()
       {

       }
       void setValue(int x)
       {
           value = x;
        }
        int getValue()
        {
           return value;
        }
        void setNext(Node x)
        {
            next = &x;
        }
        Node getNext()
        {
            return *next;
        }
     };
```

Second class:

```
    class Stack
    {
    private:
       Node *top;
    public:
        Stack()
        {
           top = NULL;
        }
        ~Stack()
        {

        }
        Node pop()
        {
            Node *temp = top;
            top = &top->getNext();
            return *temp;
        }
        void push(Node &x)
        {
            x.setNext(getTop());
            setTop(x);
        }
        Node getTop()
        {
            return *top;
        }
        void setTop(Node x)
        {
            top = &x;
        }
    };
```

and the main function:

```
    int main()
    {
       Node a;
       Node b;

       a.setValue(1);
       b.setValue(2);

       Stack s;

       s.push(a);
       s.push(b);

       cout << s.pop().getValue() << endl;
       cout << s.pop().getValue() << endl;
       return 0;
   }
```

I keep getting random numbers, I know I have a problem using objects and pointers, I just can't figure out what my problem is

Comment: have you read through the [tag:c++-faq]?

Comment: yes, but I haven't found anything similar to my code, I think it's because the whole idea of using stacks the way I did is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a pointer to the arguments to member variables is completely useless because the argument will vanish on returning from the function and the pointer will become meaningless.

```
class Node
{
private:
    int value;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node()
   {
        value = 0;
   }
   ~Node()
   {

   }
   void setValue(int x)
   {
       value = x;
    }
    int getValue()
    {
       return value;
    }
    void setNext(Node* x)      // setNext takes a pointer, not a Node by value.
    {
        next = x;
    }

    Node *getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
};
```

and

```
class Stack
{
private:
   Node *top;
public:
    Stack()
    {
       top = NULL;
    }
    ~Stack()
    {

    }
    Node pop()
    {
        Node *temp = top;
        top = top->getNext();
        return *temp;
    }
    void push(Node &x)
    {
        x.setNext(getTop());
        setTop(&x);
    }
    Node *getTop()
    {
        return top;
    }
    void setTop(Node *x)    // setTop takes a pointer, not a Node by value.
    {
        top = x;
    }
};
```

I'm afraid this implementation may be dangerous for application, but this will work here.

Comment: why do you think the implementation may be dangerous, and is there a better way to represent  a stack?

Comment: I don't think passing `Node` from outside the stack is a good idea. Instead, passing the value (`int` here) from/to the stack and hiding what data structure is used inside the stack is good.

Answer (score 0):

`Node::setNext`, `Node::getNext`, `Stack::getTop` and `Stack::setTop` all return/pass by values, which go out of scope at some point. There should be references, which will result in your stack pointing to original `Node a` and `Node b`, which go out of scope at the end of `main` when they're no longer used.

**But this is all wrong.** You should be storing copies on the heap, not just pointer to objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: what is the heap? and how should I store those copies?

Answer (score 0):

Make your getters/setters return pointers instead of objects. This code:

```
        Node *temp = top;
        top = &top->getNext();
        return *temp;
```

Will assign `temp` to `top`, then assign `top` to an address of a temporary object created by `getNext()` and then return the object `temp` is pointing to. Using `top` a next time will result in undefined behaviour because `top` is now a dangling pointer.

Node:

```
class Node
{
private:
    int value;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node()
   {
        value = 0;
   }
   ~Node()
   {

   }
   void setValue(int x)
   {
       value = x;
    }
    int getValue()
    {
       return value;
    }
    void setNext(Node* x)
    {
        next = x;
    }
    Node* getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
 };
```

Stack:

```
class Stack
{
private:
   Node *top;
public:
    Stack()
    {
       top = NULL;
    }
    ~Stack()
    {

    }
    Node pop()
    {
        Node *temp = top;
        top = top->getNext();
        return *temp;
    }
    void push(Node* x)
    {
        x->setNext(getTop());
        setTop(x);
    }
    Node* getTop()
    {
        return top;
    }
    void setTop(Node* x)
    {
        top = x;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your implementation of `Node::getNext()` is wrong because it attempt to make `Node` from `Node*`, but there are no such constructors.

Comment: @MikeCAT Forgot to change that one, thanks for spotting that.